# Laravel hasManyThrough() between tags and posts

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to get tags of a post.

This is my database with pivot table

```
post
  body

tag
  name

post_tag
  post_id
  tag_id
```

As far I can see and able to understand `hasManyThrough()` made for this. But eve I call tags() in my `Post` model

`return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'Tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');`

doesn't works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. What you're showing is a ManyToMany relation:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships

What you'd do is something like this (in Post model):

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
```

The `hasManyThrough` relation's meant as a shortcut. Given this model:

```
user
  name

post
  user_id
  body

tag
  name

post_tag
  post_id
  tag_id
```

It would come in handy when you want to see all the tags of a User (given a User is the owner of many posts) so you'd do something like this (in the User model):

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'Tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `return $this->hasManyThrough('Tag', 'Post', 'tag_id', 'post_id');` showing that the user has many `Tag`s through the `Post`s relation?